# How to get the type of a parameter on a function

Tags: go, reflection, types

I'm trying to use the type of a struct as a general parameter on a function i want to get this:

```
type comments []struct {
    ID string `json:"id"`
    Author string `json:"author"`
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

handleReadAll("/getsome")

func handleReadAll(getPath string){
    var someVar comments 
}
```

So as you can see i have that someVar as type comments, I need to make a generic use of that type so I can use the handleReadAll with generic type structs this is what I hvae tried so far:

```
handleReadAll("/getsome",comments{})

func handleReadAll(getPath string,structToDecodeArray interface{}){
    var object2 reflect.ValueOf(&structToDecodeArray)
    var object = reflect.ValueOf(&structToDecodeArray)
    fmt.Println("var",object)
    fmt.Println("var",reflect.ValueOf(&structToDecodeArray).Interface())
    fmt.Println("var",reflect.TypeOf(&structToDecodeArray))
    fmt.Println("var",reflect.ValueOf(&structToDecodeArray).Type().Elem)
}
```

I cannot make this work, I am using reflection to try to get the type of the parameter structToDecodeArray, How could I get the same var as.

```
var someVar comments
```

but with reflection.

Comment: Explain more about what handleReadAll is intended to do.  For example, will it get data from `getPath` and decode it as JSON?

Comment: @Cerise Limon I just want to use it as a regular variable after reflecting its type

Comment: Are you looking for a type assertion?  `someVar, ok := structToDecodeArray.(comments)`.

Comment: ok i could do that, but theres any way of casting like that but with reflection    someVar, ok := structToDecodeArray.(reflectedTypeSomehow)

Comment: I am still trying to understand your goal. What will you do with this variable?

Comment: The whole point is to get that variable type, for reusability of that function I could cast to a struct every time like u did but Ill have to cast it to every struct that use taht function

Comment: @RaulH: there is no "casting" going on, that is a "type assertion", which requires the type be known at compile time.

Comment: Sorry im quite new to this :D

Answer (score -1):

After some testing I manage to get it, I was sending the wrong parameter to the function I change it to this

```
var paramVar comments
handleReadAll("/getsome",paramVar)

func handleReadAll(getPath string,structToDecodeArray interface{}){
      var someVar = reflect.ValueOf(structToDecodeArray).Interface()
}
```

That would be the equivalent variable as type Interface of the parameter passed to the function just like having

```
var someVar comments
```

Comment: `var someVar = reflect.ValueOf(structToDecodeArray).Interface()` can be written more directly as `var someVar = structToDecodeArray`.

Comment: Omg I was getting an interface type before I guess I just had to change the parameter, my bad thanks man!

Comment: @CeriseLimón casting vs type.Assertion?, im new.